# "browser.setValue()" TypeError while using WebDriver.IO in Typescript

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, typeerror, webdriver-io, ui-testing

I am trying to test Google login authentication in Typescript like this:

```
it('should let you log in', () => {
        browser.url('https://www.some-website.com/');
        browser.setValue('input[name="email"]', 'some.email@domain.com');
        browser.keys('\uE007'); 
        browser.setValue('input[name="password"]', 'password!');
        browser.keys('\uE007'); 
    });
```

But I'm getting the following TypeError:

```
TypeError: browser.setValue is not a function
```

`setValue()` is indeed a function of `browser`. I double-checked the WebDriver.IO docs to confirm this. Perhaps I'm using it wrong in Typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of WDIO are you on? This is the syntax from [v4](http://v4.webdriver.io/api/action/setValue.html) -- in [v7](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/setValue/) you'd want to do `$('input[name="email"]').setValue('some.email@domain.com')` or something.